# VBA code Active X command button and For loop

Tags: vba, excel

[image: All the Fig.1 Fig.2 and Fig.3 is in the same image]

I have this code as shown below and I have tried explaining what I am doing in the code as comments.

The result that I want is also attached as image.

But, when I click that command button I only get the result as shown in Fig.1. And I have to again click the button to get the result (counts) as shown in Fig.2.
And again for the third time I have to click the button to get the results (sorted count) as shown in Fig.3.

I want to get the final result (as in Fig.3) with just one click of the command button.

I cannot understand what is going wrong since I am not getting any errors. Please help me understand the mistake in my code.
Also, please suggest how to fix this issue.

```
'I have a sheet named 'Search' which has the Active X control Command Button 'CommandButton2'
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim s1, s2 As Worksheet
Dim lrs1, lrs2, lrs3, lrs4, lrs5, lrs6, lrs7, lrs8 As Long
Dim cnt, row As Integer
Dim j, i, a As Long

'I have 2 sheets as below
Set s1 = Sheets("FG_Data")
Set s2 = Sheets("Data_Analysis")

'I am copying the Range A:B from sheet s1 to sheet s2
s1.Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Copy
s2.Paste s2.Range("B1")

'Get the last row for sheet 'FG_Data'
lrs1 = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

'Get the last row for sheet 'Data_Analysis'
'I am doing for all because the number of records are dynamic based on how many unique values of function group you get.
lrs2 = s2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
lrs3 = s2.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
lrs4 = s2.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row
lrs5 = s2.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).row
lrs6 = s2.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).row
lrs7 = s2.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).row
lrs8 = s2.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).row

'Standardizing the column hearders. Hard coding it on the cell
 s2.Range("D1") = "Function Group"
 s2.Range("E1") = "PROTUS - F"
 s2.Range("F1") = "Function Group"
 s2.Range("G1") = "PROTUS - ALP"
 s2.Range("H1") = "Function Group"
 s2.Range("I1") = "PRAudit"
 s2.Range("J1") = "Function Group"
 s2.Range("K1") = "QULIS"
 s2.Range("L1") = "Function Group"
 s2.Range("M1") = "FF1"

'Get the unique values of Function Group.
'I am getting the uniques values of Column B from that range I copied from s1 to s2
s1.Range("B2:B" & lrs1).Copy s2.Range("D2")
s2.Range("D:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

s1.Range("B2:B" & lrs1).Copy s2.Range("F2")
s2.Range("F:F").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

s1.Range("B2:B" & lrs1).Copy s2.Range("H2")
s2.Range("H:H").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

s1.Range("B2:B" & lrs1).Copy s2.Range("J2")
s2.Range("J:J").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

s1.Range("B2:B" & lrs1).Copy s2.Range("L2")
s2.Range("L:L").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

'count the number of issues for each function group in PROTUS - F Report
        For j = 2 To lrs3
            cnt = 0
            For i = 2 To lrs2
               If s2.Cells(i, 2).Value = "PROTUS - F Report" And s2.Cells(i, 3).Value = s2.Cells(j, 4).Value Then
               cnt = cnt + 1
               End If
            Next i
            s2.Cells(j, 5).Value = cnt
            cnt = 0
        Next j

'count the number of issues for each function group in PROTUS - ALP Report
        For j = 2 To lrs3
            cnt = 0
            For i = 2 To lrs2
               If s2.Cells(i, 2).Value = "PROTUS - ALP Report" And s2.Cells(i, 3).Value = s2.Cells(j, 4).Value Then
               cnt = cnt + 1
               End If
            Next i
            s2.Cells(j, 7).Value = cnt
            cnt = 0
        Next j

'count the number of issues for each function group in Product Audit report
        For j = 2 To lrs3
            cnt = 0
            For i = 2 To lrs2
               If s2.Cells(i, 2).Value = "Product Audit" And s2.Cells(i, 3).Value = s2.Cells(j, 4).Value Then
               cnt = cnt + 1
               End If
            Next i
            s2.Cells(j, 9).Value = cnt
            cnt = 0
        Next j

'count the number of issues for each function group in QULIS report
        For j = 2 To lrs3
            cnt = 0
            For i = 2 To lrs2
               If s2.Cells(i, 2).Value = "QULIS" And s2.Cells(i, 3).Value = s2.Cells(j, 4).Value Then
               cnt = cnt + 1
               End If
            Next i
            s2.Cells(j, 11).Value = cnt
            cnt = 0
        Next j

'count the number of issues for each function group in FF1 report
        For j = 2 To lrs3
            cnt = 0
            For i = 2 To lrs2
               If s2.Cells(i, 2).Value = "FF1" And s2.Cells(i, 3).Value = s2.Cells(j, 4).Value Then
               cnt = cnt + 1
               End If
            Next i
            s2.Cells(j, 13).Value = cnt
            cnt = 0
        Next j

'Sorting the count of issues data in all the columns in descending order
s2.Range("D2:E" & lrs3).Sort key1:=s2.Range("E2:E" & lrs3), _
 order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

s2.Range("F2:G" & lrs4).Sort key1:=s2.Range("G2:G" & lrs4), _
 order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

s2.Range("H2:I" & lrs5).Sort key1:=s2.Range("I2:I" & lrs5), _
 order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

s2.Range("J2:K" & lrs6).Sort key1:=s2.Range("K2:K" & lrs6), _
 order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

s2.Range("L2:M" & lrs8).Sort key1:=s2.Range("M2:M" & lrs8), _
 order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

'Standardizing the sheet color. Just some beutification of the sheet
 s2.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
 s2.Cells.Font.color = vbBlack
 s2.Cells.Font.Bold = False
 s2.Columns.AutoFit

 End Sub
```

Comment: maybe the problem is that you copy/pasted your loops and now they all use `lrs3` and `lrs2`